# Rails : Tiny-mce editor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, tinymce

I have installed tinymce-rails gem and I work fine but today I discover that when I want to edit a post the content(tinymce) of my form is blank

this is my form.html.erb

```
  <div class="article">
    <%= f.label :article %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :article, :class => "tinymce", :rows => 80, :cols => 120 %>
  </div>

<%= tinymce %>
```

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your edit action link in a "non-turbolink" enclosure.

For instance, on the bottom of your "show" template:

```
<span data-no-turbolink>
    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(@article) %>
</span>
```

Likewise in your index or wherever you link to this template from.